# rosserial and hidraw devices?

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I used `rosserial_python` to send data from my robot to my Raspberry Pi with a Bluetooth dongle but now, I want to use a 2.4 GHz WiFi dongle. The device, when I type ls /dev, appears as hidraw2.

When I try `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/hidraw2`,

I have this error : `[ERROR] [....]: Error opening serial: COuld not configure port: (22, 'Invalid argument')`

Can't I use this WiFi Dongle ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327050/rosserial-and-hidraw-devices-?/) by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well .. a `hidraw` device is not a serial port. `rosserial` works with serial ports by default. As you can see from the error, it's trying to initialise your `hidraw` device as-if it were a serial port, but fails (expectedly I'd say).

You'll either have to somehow make the `hidraw` device pretend it's a serial port, or extend `rosserial` to be able to work with your specific device.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0